# Text changed event of textBox object: how to perform text change + another action

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like that when the user is typing/changing the text of the `textBox1`, simultaneously the text of a second `textBox2` would get cleared. For doing this, I simply added an event to the form:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox2.Text = "";
    }
```

However, this is causing the `textBox2` getting cleared but the input that the user typed gets lost. Practically:

**what I expect:**
if the `textBox1` text is empty and the `textBox2` is not, when the user types "A" into the first text box I would simultaneously get the `textBox2` cleared and the letter "A" into the `textBox1`.

**what I get:**
the `textBox2` gets clear, but the letter "A" does not appear into the `textBox1`: I will have to type it a second time to get it into the right place.

What should I do to keep the user input into the `textBox1` while clearing the `textBox2`?

**EDIT:** actually forgetting to add an important part of the code, which is the "twin" brother of the method I've posted above:

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

I slightly revise my question: how can I meet my expected behavior while avoiding that the clearing in `textBox2` is taken as a text_changed event?

Comment: Is this asp.net or winforms?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not clearing the text of textbox1 somewhere ?

Comment: winforms. Sorry, I forgot to specify, I'll do it right now

Comment: The code above cannot produce that behaviour. There is something else that clears the content of the first textbox.

Comment: @mybirthname sure, I've thought about the same thing but I've just inserted it and no other code is pointing to it anyhow.

Comment: What are you doing in `textBox2` textChanged event?

Comment: There must be some other code you aren't showing, because what you've posted will do what you want. Do you have any code in the `textBox2_TextChanged` event?

Comment: Sorry guys, that was a stupid mistake. You're right, I'm not posting an important part of code which is the event in textBox2_TextChanged. I'll do it right now, it's clearly the one causing the problem, so I'll slightly revise the question to let you answer properly

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I'd strongly recommend keeping your original event handlers instead of inserting weird event binding/unbinding. Just bind to one of the keyboard events, e.g. `KeyUp` instead of `TextChanged`. Your original handlers should work fine then.

Comment: @Asad, I'm a newbie of the language and I found this approach interesting. Would you mind detailing your point please? What kind of bad things could this approach lead to? thanks in advance

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Well to start with, why go with a complicated solution when you could use a simple one? Your original handlers are concise and express what you want perfectly. They're just firing when they're not supposed to, because the event you've bound to is not the one you're actually interested in. You're interested in doing this textbox clearing stuff when, and I quote you here, "the user is **typing**", not when the `Text` property of the textbox is changed. The most straightforward way to do this is to bind to an event that fires only when the user interacts with the textbox.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Secondly, you'll need to apply this fix (or a similar one), every single time you explicitly or implicitly add code that modifies the textbox control's `Text` property. Even if you personally don't mind adding all this event attachment detachment cruft throughout your codebase, if you're collaborating with someone else, they'll probably have no intuitive idea why you're detaching and attaching handlers in quick succession, and it increases their cognitive burden to have to think about these side effects that you're trying to avoid.

Comment: @Asad - it's an interesting idea. The behaviour would be different to the accepted answer though (it's not clear what behaviour the OP wants). Imagine a button for example that sets the `textBox1.Text` to a non-empty value. In your approach the text in `textBox2` would be NOT be cleared but in the accepted answer it would. If the OP wants only one of those textboxes to have a value at any one time and they are editing it in code your approach won't work (as-is). As an aside you'd probably want to use `KeyDown` rather than `KeyUp` otherwise you get odd behaviour when tabbing.

Comment: @petelids Yes, your button example is a good demonstration of why I'm suggesting the OP use keyboard events instead. From my understanding of the question the OP wants to respond to keyboard input from the user, and programmatic changes of the `Text` property (as would occur in a button click handler) shouldn't trigger the handler.

Comment: @Asad - I think _user is typing/changing the text_ is slightly ambiguous. I read it as _any_ change to the text but I can see why you would read it the other way.

Comment: @petelids If the OP does want the other box cleared in the case of the button press it would still be clearer IMO to explicitly attach the handler for clearing the other textbox to the button click event  (in addition to any other handlers). That is a miniscule amount of code (one statement) and much more clearly expresses intent.

Comment: @Asad - that depends how many places the text is being changed from. I do like your approach though.

Comment: @petelids i.e. Call an event handler `ClearTextBox2`, and add it to the first textbox's `KeyDown` (thanks), the button's `Click`, and any other spots where you want the second textbox cleared.

Comment: I must admit this conversation is getting very interesting from a beginner point of view. I'd like to read the opinion of @Steve as well, if he doesn't mind. For you it's probably normal way of thinking but for a non-professional developer these comments are gold!

Comment: I wish to see the written code to approach this problem using the a keydown event with all the variations possible when you handle this kind of event. (Copy/Paste, Backspace) I still think that disabling the TextChanged event express perfectly the programmer intentions and it is crystal clear, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Steve I've added the written code you've requested as an answer.

Comment: @petelids In case you're interested, I believe I've come up with a compromise :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could disable your event handler to avoid one event interfere with the other one.
You could also use a global boolean variable but I prefer this approach because it requires no globals and no ifs

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox2.TextChanged -= textBox2_TextChanged;
    this.textBox2.Text = "";
    this.textBox2.TextChanged += textBox2_TextChanged;
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;
    this.textBox1.Text = "";
    this.textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: +1 & answer to @Steve, I'd say. I'm learning C# now and this approach it's working while teaching concepts about event handling to a newbie of the language. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - what a difference 10 seconds makes LOL

Comment: @petelids hehe I've indeed seen your answers, thought my laptop was crazy duplicating the screens!  I've chosen by timing since it really was the only criteria for me to choose between the two :)

Comment: @MatteoNNZ - absolutely agree. I'm glad you got your issue sorted. I'm off to practice touch typing :)

Comment: This is the wrong solution to the problem. The OP will be back where he started the moment anything else modifies the `Text` property on either of the textboxes. Not to mention both event handlers now have cryptic code inside them, even though what they're actually supposed to do is trivial. Fundamentally, the OP wants to bind his delegates to keyboard input from the user, not a change in the `Text` property. The solution is to use keyboard events instead of `TextChanged`.

Comment: @Asad you are free to propose you solution. I am very eager to see your approach and I will upvote you if you convince me that there is something simpler.

Comment: @Steve My approach is simply to use the original event handlers and bind to a keyboard event, e.g. `KeyUp` instead. There's no code whatsoever so I don't feel it even merits an answer.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend keeping your handlers nice and clean, as you have them, and instead doing one of two things:

- Using the [`Modified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.modified%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to check if the user has actually modified the textbox. This bool automatically gets reverted to false when programmatic changes to `Text` are made
- Binding to keyboard events instead

## Using `Modified`

Here's how you could implement the former option:

```
public void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    if (textBox1.Modified) textBox2.Clear(); 
}
```

This works beautifully and is easy to understand for anyone looking at the code. If the `Text` property has been changed programmatically (as in your case, by the other event handler), the `Modified` property is false, and no clearing happens.

As a bonus, if you make programmatic changes elsewhere and *do* want the event handler to follow through, you can easily set `Modified = true` explicitly:

```
textBox1.Text = @"I have been set programmatically, 
                  but in this specific case the other box 
                  should still be cleared";
textBox1.Modified = true;
```

---

## Using keyboard events

Here's how you could implement this using keyboard events:

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Clear();
}
```

And where you're doing your event handler to event binding:

```
textBox1.KeyDown += TextBox1_TextChanged;
textBox1.Paste += TextBox1_TextChanged;
```

---

## Additional improvements

You could make this a bit more generic by adding a method that binds textbox clearing logic to any other textbox. Here's how I used this in my test winforms project:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClearOnUserInput(textBox1, textBox2);
        ClearOnUserInput(textBox2, textBox1);
    }

    private void ClearOnUserInput(TextBox inputBox, TextBox target)
    {
        inputBox.TextChanged += delegate {
            if(inputBox.Modified) target.Clear();
        };
    }
}
```

Note that I've added a separate method to attach the clearing logic to keep things DRY, and I'm also using an anonymous delegate here to avoid adding extra methods. You can just as easily use two handlers as you were earlier.

Answer (score 1):

When you change the text of `textBox2` in the `TextChanged` event of `textBox1` it fires the `TextChanged` event of `textBox2` which in turn sets the `textBox1` text to `""`.

To solve it, you could remove the opposite `TextChanged` handler inside each handler before changing the text and then put it back:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox2.TextChanged -= textBox2_TextChanged;
    this.textBox2.Text = "";
    this.textBox2.TextChanged += textBox2_TextChanged;
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;
    this.textBox1.Text = "";
    this.textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to only allow one text box to accept input and always clear the other one, you can keep track of whether or not your code is changing the text in a separate variable.

Example:

```
// This variable tracks whether or not our code is changing the text
// If it's set to false, then the user is changing the text
private bool ignoreTextChange = false;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ignoreTextChange)
    {
        // Our code is changing the text, so just reset the variable
        ignoreTextChange = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Our code is going to change the other text box,
        // so set our variable and clear the other text box
        ignoreTextChange = true;
        this.textBox2.Text = "";   
    }        
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ignoreTextChange)
    {
        ignoreTextChange = false;
    }
    else
    {
        ignoreTextChange = true;
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Text Changed` event, so consider having 1 character in the textbox:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Length == 1 && textBox2.Text != String.Empty)
        textBox2.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

I will recommend you to use `Key Down` event for your scenario. It'll fire before changing the `Text` of the textbox, and your conditions will be checked at the right time.

Comment: Capturing keyboard events is the best solution, since the OP wants to trigger a delegate not when the `Text` property is changed, but when the user provides some input. This would also avoid hacky workarounds like attaching and removing listeners.